# Angular 9 SSR logs - avoid having the whole body of the main.js in our logs

Tags: node.js, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Since we changed our project to Server-Side Rendering we have a huge amount of logs coming from our client. The main problem is that every log entry has the body of the main.js in it. So about 80.000 chars in every log entry. Our logs are raising up to 30GB every day because of that.
we want to avoid logging the main.js into our logs.

What we have tried so far:

1. override for console.log with empty function in production when we are on the server-side (isServer etc.).
2. a hook for stdout and stderr on the node server to catch all outgoing logs and cut the main.js out. but even that didn´t work.

I think it should be kind of a configuration issue. I could not find out if Angular 9 or Angular Universal has some kind of log level settings. Any suggestions?

[image: example ssr log entry]

Comment: If these logs are coming from errors, maybe try to fix these errors?

Comment: Sure, you are right. But there will be new errors for sure caused by develpers. So we need to find a solution for the main issue.

Comment: Did you check if SSR is performed correctly? Depending on when an error occurs, it can stop page rendering on the server side, meaning that you'll loose the benefits of SSR

Comment: It should be never the solution to fix issues/bugs while ignoring them in the log files. Please just fix the issues and your log files will not increase as much. Otherwise you manipulate the truth ;)